# midnight commander: rules for accessing archives through VFS

Tags: iso, disk, mc, disk-image

`Midnight Commander` uses virtual filesystem (`VFS`) for displying files, such as contents of a `.tar.gz` archive, or of `.iso` image. This is configured in `mc.ext` with rules such as this one (`Open` is <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `View` is <kbd>F3</kbd>):

```
regex/\.([iI][sS][oO])$
    Open=%cd %p/iso9660://
    View=%view{ascii} isoinfo -d -i %f
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an `.iso` file, `mc` will open the `.iso` and I can browse individual files. This is very useful.

Now my question:
I have also files which are disk images, i.e. created with `pv /dev/sda1 > sda1.img`

I would like `mc` to "browse" the files inside these images in the same fashion as `.iso`.

Is this possible ? How would such rule look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is ancient, but I found myself wanting something similar, and found a possible solution (no one stop shop, but a way to solve it).

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754449/list-contents-of-floppy-image-file-without-mounting-in-linux?noredirect=1#comment118002316_66754449

Basically you'll need to put a config file in /usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/ which contains functions that perform directory listings, file IO etc. for your image file. If you can find a userspace program that does this, then it's possible. (for me, mtools was the solution, since I just need to read floppy images.)